# How to kill an ocx after creating with AtlAxAttachControl

Tags: internet-explorer, com, ocx

I need an IE ocx in my app, created dynamically, so I call CoCreateInstance and then AtlAxAttachControl. How to kill the component properly when I don't need it anymore? Just release the interface, returned by CoCreateInstance? Or just destroy the container window, used in AtlAxAttachControl? I have not found any AtlAxDetachControl function.

Comment: I think you should do both: first destroy the container window, then release the interface.